# How to test quaternion slerp

Tags: python, quaternions

I have implemented a quaternion slerp using this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp).

I understand how slerp works, my problem is that I need values to test my function. Can anyone provide examples for quaternion slerp?

The full source code is [here](https://github.com/cprogrammer1994/Pyrr/blob/slerp/pyrr/quaternion.py#L219)

```
def slerp(quat1, quat2, t):
    """Spherically interpolates between quat1 and quat2 by t.
    The parameter t is clamped to the range [0, 1]
    """

    # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp

    v0 = normalise(quat1)
    v1 = normalise(quat2)

    dot = vector4.dot(v0, v1)

    # TODO: fixlater
    # If the inputs are too close for comfort,
    # linearly interpolate and normalize the result.
    # if abs(dot) > 0.9995:
    #     pass

    # If the dot product is negative, the quaternions
    # have opposite handed-ness and slerp won't take
    # the shorter path. Fix by reversing one quaternion.
    if dot < 0.0:
        v1 = -v1
        dot = -dot

    # clamp
    dot = np.clamp(dot, -1.0, 1.0)
    theta = np.acos(dot) * t

    v2 = v1 - v0 * dot
    res = v0 * np.cos(theta) + v2 * np.sin(theta)
    return res
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `numpy-quaternion`, you could compare your results with the output of `quaternion.slerp_evaluate`. For example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import quaternion
>>> q1 = np.quaternion(1, 0, 0, 0)
>>> q2 = np.quaternion(0, 1, 0, 0)
>>> quaternion.slerp_evaluate(q1, q2, .0)
quaternion(1, 0, 0, 0)
>>> quaternion.slerp_evaluate(q1, q2, .2)
quaternion(0.951056516295154, 0.309016994374947, 0, 0)
>>> quaternion.slerp_evaluate(q1, q2, .4)
quaternion(0.809016994374947, 0.587785252292473, 0, 0)
>>> quaternion.slerp_evaluate(q1, q2, .6)
quaternion(0.587785252292473, 0.809016994374947, 0, 0)
>>> quaternion.slerp_evaluate(q1, q2, .8)
quaternion(0.309016994374947, 0.951056516295154, 0, 0)
>>> quaternion.slerp_evaluate(q1, q2, 1.)
quaternion(6.12323399573677e-17, 1, 0, 0)
```

Comment: where is `t0` defined?

Comment: @SzabolcsDombi Sorry about that, I have corrected the code.